# Releasing Cocos2d texture atlases

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How does one release a texture atlas using cocos2d?

I have the following code

```
NSString *blue= = @"Blue.plist";
CCSpriteBatchNode *blueBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Blue.png"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:blue];
[self.parentScene addChild:blueBatchNode];
```

How do I release these 2 at a laster stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"Blue.plist"]
```

Comment: Hmm I can't edit away one extraneous character so note that there is a completely unwanted > near the end of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all CCNode derived objects are auto released. So long as you use convenience methods not alloc init.

e.g.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFrameName:@"blahblah"];
```

Once your CCLayer removes the batchnode as a child, it should release that object, unless there are somehow some things linking to it, perhaps children that didn't get removed (but they should do).

Failing it being removed when that happens, you can also use purgecacheddata to clear out textures.

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
```

Purging cached data also removes cached spriteframes as mentioned in the question above.